# Asp.net+MsAccess WebApp is not correctly working on the server

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

On Local Correctly working But on the server;
Only select queries work.How can i fix this?Please Help me.Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant read/write permissions to the folder that contains the MSAccess database (.mdb/.msacc) file.  The easiest way is to grant full permission (only on that folder) to the "everyone" group.  Use "explorer" (MyComputer) to set this.